# quick check whether an elasticsearch index will return search hits

Tags: elasticsearch

We're running commands against an elasticsearch source against a few indices like so:

```
curl -XGET 'http://es-server:9200/logstash-2015.01.28,logstash-2015.01.27/_search?pretty' -d @/a_query_file_in_json_format
```

Works great most of the time, and we can parse the results we need.

However when the indices are in a bad state-- maybe there's been a lag in indexing, or some shards are acting up-- the query above will return no results, and it's impossible to know whether it's because there's no matching records or the index is unstable in some way.

I've been looking at the [elastic search indices recovery API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-recovery.html) but am a bit overwhelmed.  Are there some queries I can run that will give a yes/no answer to 'can a search against these indices be relied upon at the moment?'

Comment: `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v"` will show the shard state and number of documents in a shard - is that of help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways to get this information.

1) You can use the [cluster health API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html#cluster-health) at the indices level like this :

```
GET _cluster/health/my_index?level=indices
```

This will output the status of the cluster, with information about status and shards of the index `my_index` :

```
{
   "cluster_name": "elasticsearch_thomas",
   "status": "yellow",
   "timed_out": false,
   "number_of_nodes": 1,
   "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
   "active_primary_shards": 5,
   "active_shards": 5,
   "relocating_shards": 0,
   "initializing_shards": 0,
   "unassigned_shards": 5,
   "indices": {
      "my_index": {
         "status": "yellow",
         "number_of_shards": 5,
         "number_of_replicas": 1,
         "active_primary_shards": 5,
         "active_shards": 5,
         "relocating_shards": 0,
         "initializing_shards": 0,
         "unassigned_shards": 5
      }
   }
}
```

2) If you want to have a less verbose answer, or to filter only on some specific information, you can rely on the [_cat](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) API, which allows you to customize the output. However, the output is no longer a JSON.

For example, if you want only the name and health status of the indices, the following request will do the trick :

```
GET _cat/indices/my_index?h=index,health&v
```

by outputting this :

```
index    health 
my_index yellow
```

Note that the column headers are shown only because of the verbose flag (`v` GET parameter in the previous request).

To have a complete list of what columns are available, use the `help` parameter :

```
GET _cat/indices?help
```