# Check whether an index is up to date?

Tags: elasticsearch

A while ago I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196759/quick-check-whether-an-elasticsearch-index-will-return-search-hits) about elasticsearch indices and how to check their general health.

I had some terrific responses, and have incorporated them, but recently I've encountered a situation whereby the index in question hadn't been updated for a while.  Consequently my queries against it returned either no data, or an abnormally small amount.

The index health remained 'green' throughout and so I was wondering if it was possible to tell whether an index was being updated, what rate it's happening at, and/or the last time an index was updated with new data?  That way I could get a sense for how 'busy' it was and draw conclusions from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi using the stats API you can ask for a lot of information about the index. You can ask for the amount of inserts, searches, etc. In your case you probably want to have a look at the amount of refreshes. After a refresh the documents are available for search. It does not give the moment there was a refresh the last time though. Below part of the response to the following request:

GET /gridshore/_stats/refresh

```
   "indices": {
      "gridshore-20141224151357": {
         "primaries": {
            "refresh": {
               "total": 1,
               "total_time_in_millis": 0
            }
         },
         "total": {
            "refresh": {
               "total": 1,
               "total_time_in_millis": 0
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

More information on the stats api can be found here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html

Another option would be to use the marvel plugin, that plugin keeps a history also of the refreshes that occurred.